# Is it possible to have 2 aliases assigned to 1 device token with Urban Airship?

Tags: urbanairship.com

We are using Urban Airship, and there is a case where 2 or 3 aliases can be registered to the same device.

Is it possible to have 2 aliases assigned to 1 device token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/connect_audience.html#aliases

You can have multiple tags set to a device, but aliases and device tokens have a 1:1 relationship when it comes to Urban Airship.